# Proving Algorithms with Logarithms

Tags: algorithm, big-o, analysis, logarithm

I know how to prove algorithms, but I'm not sure how to go about proving exponential and logarithmic ones:

Ex:
`Given f(n) = 1.05^n and g(n) = n^2, determine if f(n)=O(g(n))`

Ex: `Given f(n) = (log-base4 of n) and g(n) = (log-base2 of n), determine if f(n)=bigTheta(g(n))`

Ex: `Given f(n) = 4^n, and g(n) = 2^n, determine if f(n)=O(g(n)).`

I'm not looking for solutions (I wouldn't mind a detailed example though), but rather an explanation of how to solve these kinds of problems. The ones I mentioned above are a few different ones that I've run into which I'm confused about.

Comment: I found that most such problems are solved by induction, where you prove a trivial case (n=1); assume true for all n to x; then prove x+1 by rearranging terms such that you get your n case and your base case.

Comment: I'm looking for another, more direct way of proving it. (Such as solving c1, c2, n0)

Answer (score 2):

Asymptotically, n! >> aⁿ >> nᵃ >> nlogn >> n >> logn >> a (constant).
So, if f=1.5ⁿ=aⁿ and g=n²=nᵃ, you can see that f >> g for sufficiently large value of n.
So, g=O(f) and f=Ω(g), asymptotically.

Similarly, f=log₂n >> g=log₄n, so f=Ω(g).

And 4ⁿ >> 2ⁿ. So if f=4ⁿ and g=2ⁿ, f=Ω(g).

Comment: This is not a proof though, which the OP seeks.